# Parsing GET JSON reply without keys to object in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am currently consuming content in the style of

```
"potter",["potter harry","potter","potter hallows 2","potter collection","potter hallows 1","potter dvd box","potter 7","potter hallows","potter blue ray","potter feniks"],[{"xcats":[{"name":"dvd_all"},{"name":"books_nl"}]},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],[]]
```

Using the following code in Spring

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String information = restTemplate.getForObject(URL, String.class);
//further parsing of information, using String utilities
```

Obviously this is not the way to go, because I should be able to automatically parse it somehow. I will also only need the content of the second element as well (the array, from `potter harry` to `potter feniks`).

What is the best way to parse a GET response like that, when its json contents aren't name-valued?

Comment: first of all the consuming content is not well formatted JSON also in the rest template you can pass what object you want and if spring rest template has suitable message converter it will "automatically" parse the response. ex: `ResponseEntity<Map<String,AdInsightDataMixin>> entity = getTemplate().exchange(builder.toUri(),
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, AdInsightDataMixin>>() {
                });`

Comment: Well, how would I create a suitable message converter for a response like that, which has no keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following helper class enabled me to easily parse the response and get the list I needed

```
public class JSONHelper {

private static final JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);

public static List<String> getListOnPosition(int i, String inputWithFullList) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(inputWithFullList);
    ArrayNode node = (ArrayNode) rootNode.get(i);
    if (!node.isArray()) {
        result.add(node.asText());
    } else {
        for (final JsonNode subNode : node) {
            result.add(subNode.asText());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

Some JUnit tests for this scenario

```
public class JSONHelperTest {
@Test
public void parseListOnPositionFullListTest() throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
    String inputWithFullList = "[\"a\",[\"b\", \"c\", \"d\"],[],[]]";
    List<String> result = JSONHelper.getListOnPosition(1, inputWithFullList);
    assertEquals(3, result.size());
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("b", "c", "d"), result);
}

@Test
public void parseListOnPositionOneElementListTest() throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
    String inputWithFullList = "[\"a\",[\"b\"],[],[]]";
    List<String> result = JSONHelper.getListOnPosition(1, inputWithFullList);
    assertEquals(1, result.size());
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("b"), result);
}

@Test
public void parseListOnPositionEmptyListTest()  throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
    String inputWithFullList = "[\"a\",[],[],[]]";
    assertTrue(JSONHelper.getListOnPosition(1, inputWithFullList).isEmpty());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public  void testJson(){
    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<ArrayNode> entity = template.
            exchange("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2rl7m", HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<ArrayNode>() {
            });

    ArrayNode body = entity.getBody();
    body.get(1).forEach(m->{
        System.out.println(m.asText());});
}
```

But my advice is if you can change the response type not to be json array with mixed value types in it will be better

Comment: What exactly don't you get?

Comment: this url to amazon and did you help you my answer?